# Получение значений из строки

Tags: c#

Есть массив из строк вида "          в точке  X=5627.6796  Y=-9038.5520  Z=   0.0000"
Нужно получить значение x и y и добавить их последовательно в другой массив.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Разделить, расщепить - по-английски Split. Вдруг поможет?

Comment: Смотря как варьируются строки, может простой сплит, а может регулярка нужна.

Comment: Странный вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
int position = inputString.IndexOf('X');
string XString = inputString.Substring(position + 2);
position = XString.IndexOf(' ');
XString = XString.Substring(0, position);
double x  =double.Parse(XString);
```

для Y аналогично.

Comment: лучше через регулярки
и в случае если парс не сработает - то логировать куда-то неспарсенные данные